# Adding values to a row on google sheets appends to the bottom of list instead of the top

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an appscript on google sheets to implement reorder levels. I currently have a sheet called Reorder Levels Master. Through API's, it takes in live inventory from our Retail software and when stock reaches a predetermined threshold, it outputs "Yes" in a column alongside the qty to reorder, and the value to reorder. On a separate sheet, it inputs the SKU ID, SKU Name, Order Qty, and Order Value for our purchasing team to place a purchase order. Goal is to insert a row on the 2nd row, and then paste the values into the second row instead of the bottom of the sheet. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Reorder Levels Master');

  // Define column indices for "place reorder", "order qty", and "order value"
  var placeReorderColumn = 16;
  var orderQtyColumn = 17; 
  var orderValueColumn = 18;

  // Define the target sheet
  var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Reorders');

  // Check if the edited cell is in the "place reorder" column and has a value of yes
  if (e.range.getColumn() === placeReorderColumn && e.value.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    // Get the data from the row
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    // Append the data to the target sheet with "PO needs to be made" as the default status
    var targetRowIndex = 2
    var poDateAndTime = new Date(); // Current date and time
    targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
    targetSheet.appendRow([poDateAndTime, rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[orderQtyColumn - 1], rowData[orderValueColumn - 1], '', '', '', 'PO needs to be made']);

    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['PO needs to be made', 'PO Made, awaiting delivery', 'GRN Received']).build();
    targetSheet.getRange(2, targetSheet.getRange(1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()).getColumn()).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Problem i'm running into, is that it's creating a row in the 2nd row spot, but then pasting the data into the bottom of the list.
[image]

After 2 test entries were added, a row is inserted at the top, then the data is pasted at the bottom. Any idea how to fix this to get it to paste to the top?

Tried inserting a row and appending it to the next available row but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

Instead of using append row, change this:

```
targetSheet.appendRow([poDateAndTime, rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[orderQtyColumn - 1], rowData[orderValueColumn - 1], '', '', '', 'PO needs to be made']);
```

To this:

```
var arr = [poDateAndTime, rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[orderQtyColumn - 1], rowData[orderValueColumn - 1], '', '', '', 'PO needs to be made']

targetSheet.getRange(2,1,1,9).setValues(arr);
```

Final look:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Reorder Levels Master');

  // Define column indices for "place reorder", "order qty", and "order value"
  var placeReorderColumn = 16;
  var orderQtyColumn = 17; 
  var orderValueColumn = 18;

  // Define the target sheet
  var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Reorders');

  // Check if the edited cell is in the "place reorder" column and has a value of yes
  if (e.range.getColumn() === placeReorderColumn && e.value.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    // Get the data from the row
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    // Append the data to the target sheet with "PO needs to be made" as the default status
    var targetRowIndex = 2
    var poDateAndTime = new Date(); // Current date and time
    targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);

    var arr = [poDateAndTime, rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[orderQtyColumn - 1], rowData[orderValueColumn - 1], '', '', '', 'PO needs to be made']
    targetSheet.getRange(2,1,1,9).setValues([arr]);

    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['PO needs to be made', 'PO Made, awaiting delivery', 'GRN Received']).build();
    targetSheet.getRange(2, targetSheet.getRange(1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()).getColumn()).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

`setValues()` overwrites the cell value based on the given range. Given, that you define the number of columns needed for the data.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the help. One edit that I had to make was     var arr = [[reorderDateAndTime, rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[orderQtyColumn - 1], rowData[orderValueColumn - 1], '', '', '', 'PO needs to be made']] needed to be a 2d array. Otherwise setValues(arr); returns an error

Comment: Thanks for pointing the 2D array part, that was my miss. Edited my answer to reflect the correct format